# Difficulty understanding the use of arbitrary function for the worst case running time of an algorithm

Tags: time-complexity

In CLRS the author said

"Technically, it is an abuse to say that the running time of insertion sort is $O(n^2)$,
since for a given $n$, the actual running time varies, depending on the particular
input of size $n$. When we say “the running time is $O(n^2)$,” we mean that there is a
function $f(n)$ that is $O(n^2)$ such that for any value of $n$, no matter what particular
input of size $n$ is chosen, the running time on that input is bounded from above by
the value $f(n)$. Equivalently, we mean that the worst-case running time is $O(n^2)$.
"

What I have difficulties understanding is why did the author talked about an arbitrary function $f(n)$ instead of directly $n^2$.

I mean why didn't the author wrote

"When we say “the running time is $O(n^2)$,” we mean that for any value of $n$, no matter what particular input of size $n$ is chosen, the running time on that input is bounded from above by
the value $cn^2$ for some +ve $c$ and sufficiently large n. Equivalently, we mean that the worst-case running time is $O(n^2)$".

I have very limited understanding of this subject so please forgive me if my question is too basic.

Comment: "is bounded from above by the value $cn^2$ for some $+$ve $c$" is not exactly what $O(n^2)$ says. For example, $cn^2$ is always $0$ for $n=0$ and $0$ might not be a bound for the running time, for an input of that size. You need to add $n>n_0$, for some $n_0$.

Comment: Regarding $f$, the function is not arbitrary. There are conditions for it, which are mentioned. I think what you mean is why did they name a function that constitutes a bound for the running time for all inputs of a given size. That was just style. With some fixes, your wording can also say the same while not giving the bound any name.

Comment: I edited the question to mention the condition of $n \ge n_0$. Is my and the author's statement identical now?

Comment: Note CLRS has four authors.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the point that the authors are trying to make is the following:

> The exact running time depends on the input.

When we say that the running time of insertion sort is $O(n^2)$, what we really mean is:

> The worst-case running time of insertion sort is $O(n^2)$.

Actually, we could be even more verbose, and mention that by *worst-case* we mean worst case with respect to the length of the array:

> The worst-case running time of insertion sort, in terms of the length $n$ of the input, is some function $f(n)$ which belongs to the class $O(n^2)$.

This is *equivalent* to the following claim:

> There exists $C$ such that insertion sort takes time at most $Cn^2$ when running on an input of length $n$.

Note that there is no need to specify a lower bound on $n$ – if the running time is bounded by $C_1n^2$ for all $n \geq N$, then it is bounded by $C_2n^2$ for all $n \geq 1$. You can take $C_2$ to be the maximum between $C_1$ and the worst-case running times on inputs of length at most $N$.